# what is benefit of using a clean function in Python Class

Tags: django, class, python-2.7

I have seen a clean function defined in many classes of Python but never sees it calling explicitly . For what this clean function is meant for ?

Is this is called automatically like `__init__()` function ?

Comment: Never seen one, please provide an example. No, I don't think anything named like that is called automatically.

Comment: Actually that is source code of a website so I won't able to post the part as it has many dependencies in other files.

Answer (score 6):

No, the `.clean()` method is specific to Django.

It is not a general Python convention.

It is only used on `Model` classes, to provide custom model validation or on `Form` and various `Field` classes for forms for the same sort of tasks. The Django framework calls these methods when handling form input.

See [Form and field validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/validation/) for more information on when `.clean()` is called.

See the [`Model.clean()` method documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) to see how this applies to model validation.